# Grails global Variable based redirect

Tags: grails, redirect

I have a grails application which I'm building a global config page for (application name, image etc etc.)

I want to redirect any url request to it if a boolean is false. I would see this to be something like :

```
AppConfiguration config = AppConfiguration.findAll().get(0);
if(config == null || !config.hasBeenConfigured)
{
    redirect([controller :"AppConfiguration", action:"index"])
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this without trawling through the 100s of controllers to add this in.

Grails Version 3.0.8

Thanks

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Sorry! version 3.0.8, I'll update the question now also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.

Every controller implemented a main layout for resources etc via :

```
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
```

So in this main.gsp I added the following bits of code :

```
<g:set var="config" bean="configurationService"/>
<script>
    var shouldRedirect = ${!config.hasBeenConfigured()};

    if(shouldRedirect && window.location.href.indexOf("AppConfiguration") == -1)
    {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/AppConfiguration/index";
    }
</script>
```

And created a grails service called ConfigurationService like so :

```
class ConfigurationService {

    def hasBeenConfigured()
    {
        return AppConfiguration.instance.hasBeenConfigured;

    }

    def getApplicationName()
    {
        return AppConfiguration.instance.applicationName;
    }
}
```